# how to make user emeditor to wait till user input window is closed

Tags: emeditor

i have some code in which user has to give some information and based on the user information subsequent code will be executed. **strong text**can we make emeditor to wait till the user window is closed.**strong text**

```
clipboardData.setData("Text", "");
wnd = shell.FindWindow( "", "Playlist" );
wnd.SetForeground();
Sleep( 1000 );
shell.SendKeys( "^a" );
Sleep( 100 );
shell.SendKeys( "^%c" );
Editor.newfile();
Sleep(500); 
document.selection.Paste(eeCopyUnicode);

if( !editor.EnableTab ){ 
   editor.EnableTab = true; 
   alert( "Please run this macro again." ); 
   Quit(); 
}

**strong text**sFind = prompt( "This macro extracts lines that do contain any of the specified multiple strings separated by |:", "" );**strong text**
if( sFind == "" ){
    Quit();
}
var sArr = sFind.split("|");
batch_list = editor.filters;
for( i = 0; i < sArr.length; ++i ) {
    batch_list.AddFind(sArr[i],0,0);
}
//document.selection.BatchFind(batch_list, eeFindExtract | eeFindLineOnly,0);
document.selection.BatchFind(batch_list,  eeFindExtract | eeFindLineOnly,0);

document.selection.SelectAll();  // select all text

document.selection.Copy(eeCopyUnicode);  // copy the seleciton to the Clipboard
WshShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );

WshShell.Run ( "PotPlayerMini64.exe /clipboard" );
```

in the above code, **strong text**before i close prompt window subsequent code is getting executed. i want to stop execution of subsequent code, before prompt window is closed.**strong text** is it possible.

Comment: It's hard to read your question. Do you know the name of the window title that you are waiting for closing? Please correct your question styling (`strong text`), and clarify your question possibly with screenshots and step-by-step procedure.

Comment: Please post only a related portion of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: i want to wait till EmEditorPrompt window is closed. the related code is

Comment: sFind = prompt( "This macro extracts lines that do contain any of the specified multiple strings separated by |:", "" );

Comment: The macro will pause while waiting for user input at `prompt()`.

Comment: in the original code i posted above, it is not pausing. the code lines below prompt() are getting executed even before prompt() is closed. please see my first code.

Comment: `prompt()` is designed to pause until user enters something and click OK or Cancel. Please create a `minimal reproducible sample` so that we can test.